# London system move order nuances Qb6 without Nc6

Tags: opening, theory, 1.d4, london-system, transpositions

In the London system, playing early Nd2 is recommended to react against Qb6. For example if we take this move order

```
       [FEN ""]
       1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 Nf6 3. e3 c5 4. c3 Nc6 5. Nd2 Qb6 6. Qb3 c4 7. Qc2 g6 {[%draw arrow,c8,f5,red]} 8. e4
```

White has managed to stop the **Bf5** and at the same time managed to break open the center

Now if we look at this move order

```
       [FEN ""]
       1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 Nf6 3. e3 c5 4. c3 Qb6 5. Qb3 c4 6. Qc2 g6 {[%draw arrow,c8,f5,red]}
```

Now notice that black didn't include **Nc6** so white is 1 tempo short of breaking with **e4**. Black will manage to chase the Queen with **Bf5** (possible to c1?) and will complete the development as usual.

So how should I react when the Queen comes out early as above? Am I left with no choice but to play with the queen on c1

Comment: @AndrewChin https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/42293/23596 I think black has an easy plan against the q exchange which I don't feel comfortable with

Comment: I would simply play Nf3. Really on move 2 already. :D But also after 3...c5 4.Nf3 and if Qb6 you can play Nc3 or other moves.

Comment: In your first line 5...Qb6 is a bad move. There are better options for black, for example 5...Bf5

Answer (score 1):

I think White reacted well when the Black Queen came out. As mentioned by koedem, playing Nf3 earlier, specifically 4.Nf3 in both variations, might make sense.

From Black's perspective, 4..Nc6 and 4..Qb6 are equally good. The only move I do not like is 6..c4 in the first variation. 6..g6 or 6..e6 seem stronger.

Answer (score 0):

When White is force to play Qc1 he simply develops with Nf3, Be2, h3 and the Bf5 is in trouble after g4. White can play g4 because the black Queen is on the queenside, I guess.